# More efficient method than .empty() to avoid duplicates when populating <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, validation

I am creating a form. I am trying to build a list which is dynamically populated with items representing valueless input fields from this form. I have created a simplified version in a fiddle to illustrate my issue. Essentially, I have the error list being created as I want. It successfully counts blank input fields and updates this count when data is entered or deleted and populates the list accordingly. However, to avoid duplicate entries in this list I am currently emptying it on each call. This seems fairly inefficient and, as you see on the fiddle, it runs it's empty and build functions immediately after a blur, so if an input is in focus and one attempts to click an error link, it takes a couple of clicks before it scrolls to the empty input in question. So my question is, is there another way I can avoid duplicate entries and it run fast enough so that it can fun the scroll function on click immediately from focus?

I hope this is clear enough. I added some white space to allow for a scroll effect so you can witness the multiple clicks required before the scroll occurs).

```js
$(function(){

  var submit = $('input[type="submit"]');
  var monday = $("input[name='MONDAY']");
  var tuesday = $("input[name='TUESDAY']");
  var wednesday = $("input[name='WEDNESDAY']");
  
  $('input').eq(0).focus();
  
  // disable submit 
  submit.attr("disabled", true);
  
  // call formValidate on load and on input blur
  formValidate();
  $('input').blur(function(){
    formValidate();
  });
  
  function formValidate(){
      // inputs 
      monday = $("input[name='MONDAY']");
      tuesday = $("input[name='TUESDAY']");
      wednesday = $("input[name='WEDNESDAY']");
      
      // store values of inputs in vars
      var inputCheck = {
          'monday':       monday.val(),
          'tuesday':      tuesday.val(),
          'wednesday':    wednesday.val()
      };

      var myErrors = [];

      myErrors.splice(0,myErrors.length);
      
      // if input has no value, add to error array
      $.each( inputCheck, function(key, value){
          if (value === '') {
             myErrors.push(key);
          }
      });
      
      // if any errors, create li for each
      if (myErrors.length > 0 ) {
      
          // display errors div
          $('.errors').addClass('exist');
          $('.errors').find('span').html(myErrors.length);
          
          // empty ul to avoid duplicate entries
          $('.error-box-item ul').empty();
          
          // populate ul with any errors
          $.each(myErrors, function(i) {
            var li = $('<li>');
            var link = myErrors[i].replace("-", " ");
            var formattedLink = toTitleCase(link);
            var tag = "#err-" + myErrors[i];
            var a = $('<a></a>').attr("href", tag);
            a.append(formattedLink);
            li.append(a);
            $('.error-box-item ul').append(li);

          });
      } else {
      
          // if no errors, hide error info and 
          // enable the submit button
          $('.errors').removeClass('exist');
          submit.attr("disabled", false);
      }

  } // end validate form

  function toTitleCase(str) {
    return str.replace(/(?:^|\s)\w/g, function(match) {
      return match.toUpperCase();
    });
  }
  
    
  // scroll to link
  $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
      if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: target.offset().top - 50
          }, 500);
          return false;
        }
      }
    }); // end scroll 
    
}); // end ready
```

```css
.errors {
display: none;
}
.errors.exist {
display: block;
}
.demo-space {
height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <p>Monday:</p>
  <input id="err-monday" type="number" name="MONDAY">
  <p>Tuesday:</p>
  <input id="err-tuesday" type="number" name="TUESDAY">
  <p>Wednesday:</p>
  <input id="err-wednesday" type="number" name="WEDNESDAY">
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
  </p>
</form>
<div class="demo-space"></div>
<div class="errors">
  You have <span></span> errors:
  <div class="error-box-item">
    <ul class="list">
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="demo-space"></div>
```

Comment: Seems like only real issue is you should delegate the click listener since those elements are dynamically generated

Comment: @charlietfl can you explain any further?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: @charlietfl that won't fix the issue, unfortunately.

Comment: building a new `ul` outside of the dom, and replacing the old `ul` to the new `ul` in one operation would be much faster.

Comment: What exactly is your issue? The links that you rebuild won't have listeners attached unless you attach them after they are created, or delegate the listener. Beyond that, the dom manipulation is not really that significant for just a few elements